# Comparing time series data between three treatment groups (in R)

Tags: r, nls, p-value

I have time series data where the response is decreasing over time. The rate of the decrease is supposed to depend on the treatment (the concentration of a drug). By looking at the data I am not sure that the data will show a significant difference between treatments but I need to show this statistically, with a p-value. What type of statistical analysis does one need to perform to do this? The data can be fit with the first order rate equation R = R_0 * exp(-k * t).

sample data:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = structure(list(time = c(0, 0, 5, 5, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40),
                    conc_A = c(0.9957, 1.004, 0.9074, 0.8415, 0.8033, 0.7782, 0.6642, 0.6504, 0.6183, 0.6347, 0.48, 0.5222, 0.3737, 0.4229),
                    conc_B = c(1.054, 0.9463, 0.8999, 0.775, 0.738, 0.6598, 0.6498, 0.6078, 0.5878, 0.552, 0.4826, 0.4218, 0.3624, 0.2902),
                    conc_C = c(0.9735, 1.026, 0.7553, 0.82, 0.6976, 0.6548, 0.5795, 0.531, 0.4751, 0.4508, 0.3259, 0.3688, 0.2806, 0.244)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))

melt.df <- melt(df, id.vars = 'time', variable.name = 'treatment', value.name = 'response')
plot.df <- ggplot(melt.df, aes(time, response, color = treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic()
plot.df
```

[quick plot of the provided data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plHFo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the data to long form. Using that run a linear model against time, `fm0`, to get starting values and then run the corresponding non-linear model, `fm1`.  Then run a model similar to `fm1` but with the concentation name added.  Finally perform an anova between `fm2` and `fm1`. We see that concentration is highly significant.

```
library(tidyr)
long <- pivot_longer(df, -time)

fm0 <- nls(log(value) ~ log(R) - k * time, long, start = list(R = 1, k = 1))
fm1 <- nls(value ~ R * exp(-k * time), long, start = coef(fm0))

R <- coef(fm1)[[1]]
k <- coef(fm1)[[2]]
st <- list(RA = R, kA = k, RB = R, kB = k, RC = R, kC = k)
fm2 <- nls(value ~ 
        (RA * exp(-kA * time)) * (name == "conc_A") + 
        (RB * exp(-kB * time)) * (name == "conc_B") +
        (RC * exp(-kC * time)) * (name == "conc_C"), long, 
        start = st)
anova(fm1, fm2)
```

giving:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: value ~ R * exp(-k * time)
Model 2: value ~ (RA * exp(-kA * time)) * (name == "conc_A") + (RB * exp(-kB * time)) * (name == "conc_B") + (RC * exp(-kC * time)) * (name == "conc_C")
  Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df   Sum Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
1     40   0.151207                                  
2     36   0.051482  4 0.099725  17.434 4.866e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Another thing to do is to look at the model which has a common R among the concentrations but different k values and compare that to each of the two models above.  The three R values from `fm2` are nearly the same so it is likely that that reduced model can be used in place of `fm2`.